Moulding rubber
I need rubber tubes of a certain diameter, wall thickness comparable to latex gloves.
For this I took a glass rod as the inner mould, and dipped it in liquid rubber cement. The rubber tube forms fine. I powder the outer side, but since the inner side in touch with glass is not powder, when I remove it from the glass rod, the inner side collapses and sticks together.
How do I prevent that?

air ............

would air work in separating them after they are stuck?

you asked How do I prevent that?

would air work in separating them after they are stuck? ... what is preventing you from testing that?

@jsotola where do I get the air? i do not have a manufacturing set up with high pressure air with nozzle outlet. Water water everywhere...

-- by turning it inside out as you roll it off the glass.
